# How to retrieve Internet (Message) Headers via Office 365 REST API?

Tags: python, rest, ms-office, exchangewebservices, office365

I am currently working on a project in python to interface with the Office365 REST API, but I need to retrieve (all of) the Internet Message Headers for specific emails.

I've used the $metadata file to research the exposed properties and I don't see an obvious method to access this information.

I know that you can access the headers in OWA using "Message Details" so I would think that the information is web-accessible (even if it is not through the REST API).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible in 2019.

In your `$select` parameter, you can now specify `InternetMessageHeaders` to get all the MIME message headers.

Tested using this Postman request:

https://gist.github.com/elliotfiske/ccf81266be6ead10823a53c094749234

Be sure to substitute in your own Bearer auth token.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's not supported currently, but on the roadmap to add according to this answer:

[How to fetch email headers with Office 365 Mail REST APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175129/how-to-fetch-email-headers-with-office-365-mail-rest-apis)