# How to fetch email headers with Office 365 Mail REST APIs?

Tags: rest, email, office365, exchangewebservices

I can't seem to find a way to fetch raw RFC 2822 email headers from the message resource https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesMessage

All the standard headers To, From, Subject are available. How do I get a list of headers[] other than the standard once such as "Received", "Delivered-To", etc.. Is this feature not yet supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Igor - Office 365 REST API doesn't currently support returning the RFC 2822 email headers.  This is on our roadmap to add, but we don't have a firm timeline yet.

Comment: It's been a year since this answer. Has the status of this item changed?

Comment: Looks like some partial support is there now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103388/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-rfc-2822-or-any-headers-from-an-email-with-the