# Set a custom header with Outlook/Office 365 REST

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

I know it is possible to [get the headers from an email with this Outlook REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103388/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-rfc-2822-or-any-headers-from-an-email-with-the), but is there a way that we can set custom headers as well? I can't seem to find any documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting the [SingleValueExtendedProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/extended-properties-rest-operations#ExtendedpropertyoperationsCreateextendedpropertyinanewitem) on the message object. You can try using the property id for [PS_INTERNET_HEADERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg318108.aspx) - {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}.

Creating a new message with a custom header might look something like this:

```
POST https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages

Content-Type: application/json
{
    ...,
    "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "PropertyId":"String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name x-my-custom-header",
            "Value":"Some Value"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: works like a charm - just wish this was highlighted on their office api documentation instead of being hidden deep ...