# How to get new dates from event message on microsoft graph?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm new to both StackOverflow and Microsoft Graph.

I'm facing the following problem:

- I get an `EventMessage` from a technical mailbox that contains an update of the involved event.
- I would like to get new values from this event (ie new start dates / new end dates).

Further explanations :

- An event is created by the organizer's mailbox with some other users as attendees.
- From his webmail, this attendee can update this event - delegate it or update his dates.
- It automatically sends an email that I can read from the technical mailbox.
- This email contains the event but doesn't contain event's updates proposal.

How I did :

1. I created an event from a user, with an attendee, using outlook.
2. The event's attendee updated the event asking for new dates, with the webmail client (using option "propose new time").
3. It sends a mail to the organizer to notify the changes.

I'm now trying to get changes from the mail message received on the organizer's mailbox (ie : new dates).

To get the `eventMail`, I use the following request

```
/v1.0/users/{user}/messages/{id}?$expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event
```

It gives me the `microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event` object.

I would like to get those updates.

Comment: And, what have you tried/done ? Any code ? This isn't a code writing service, you should comme here with a [mcve] of a very specific problem as defined in the [ask] page.

Comment: Ok, sorry for my incomplete description.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do. Are you talking about "Propose New Time"?

Comment: Yeah, this is a little hard to follow who are the actors and what actions each actor made. Can you clarify the action that the attendee made at step 2 under how I did? It sounds like the attendee, from a client like Outlook, accepted||tentativeaccept||declined the event and proposed a new meeting. An eventMessage is sent back to the organizer that gives the attendees response. But you are looking for the proposed times on that eventMessage that is sent to the organizer, correct?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @MichaelMainer, it's exactly what i wanted to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proposed start date and proposed end date from this message are not supported by current version of the API.
But it's is possible to access it with such request
 `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[userid]/messages/[messageid]?$select=SingleValueExtendedProperties&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter%3Did+eq+'SystemTime+%7B00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046%7D+Id+0x8250'+or+id+eq+'SystemTime+%7B00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046%7D+Id+0x8251'+or+id+eq+'SystemTime+%7B6ED8DA90-450B-101B-98DA-00AA003F1305%7D+Id+0x00000009')`
the keypoints are : 
- $select=**SingleValueExtendedProperties**
- $expand=**SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Some id')**

I found my properties ids there 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee237457%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

For start date it is
**SystemTime {00062002-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8250**

For end date it is 
**SystemTime {00062002-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8251**

My solution started from this post 
[Is it possible to retrieve the RFC 2822 (or any) headers from an email with the Outlook/Office 365 REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103388/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-rfc-2822-or-any-headers-from-an-email-with-the/46588981#46588981)

Comment: Nice digging on finding the extended property definition.

Comment: Hi Joceleyn, thanks for this AMAZING solution. My current problem is that I can't find an event identifier in the message information. How have you been able to deal with this?

Comment: hi Konrad, I hope my answer will help you. As I understood, an event has one identifier as Event shared with all attendees. and each event as an unique identifier for each instance. I mean, one identifier for Attendee A, one identifier for Attendee B... For my needs, i used icalUid value coupled with user's account. Please feel free to upgrade / correct my post. I face some problems with explaining such things in english.