# Is it possible to get email header from SENT item with OWA rest-api?

Tags: outlook-restapi

According to this question [Is it possible to retrieve the RFC 2822 (or any) headers from an email with the Outlook/Office 365 REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103388/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-rfc-2822-or-any-headers-from-an-email-with-the)
by doing

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages$select=InternetMessageHeaders
```

But I can get the header **only for inbox items**, I need to retrieve  the header for the sent items as well!

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but I don't believe sent items have Internet headers. I attempted to view them in Microsoft Outlook and for a sent email they are blank. Thinking further, the headers typically contain the details of how the message was delivered from the sender to the recipient - which is only available at the recipient's end. The sender has no way of knowing how the message is being delivered. Please let me know if I'm incorrect or overlooking something.

Comment: Thanks for respond,
yeah actually when I think about it... it makes sense, I think it is not the actually sent mail but merely a copy of it , I thought they could still have done it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using the `$value` parameter to get the MIME type of the message and read the entire header!

From [Example 4 - Get message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```sh
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/4aade2547798441eab5188a7a2436bc1/$value
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/plain

Received: from contoso.com (10.194.241.197) by 
contoso.com (10.194.241.197) with Microsoft 
SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, 
cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256) id 15.1.1374.0 via Mailbox 
Transport; Mon, 4 Sep 2017 03:00:08 -0700 
Received: from contoso.com (10.194.241.197) by 
contoso.com (10.194.241.197) with Microsoft 
SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, 
cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256) id 15.1.1374.0; Mon, 4 Sep 
2017 03:00:07 -0700 
Received: from contoso.com 
(fe80::5bf:5059:4ca0:5017) by contoso.com 
(fe80::5bf:5059:4ca0:5017%12) with mapi id 15.01.1374.000; Mon, 4 Sep 2017 
03:00:01 -0700 
From: Administrator <admin@contoso.com> 
To: Administrator <admin@contoso.com> 
Subject: This email has attachment. 
Thread-Topic: This email has attachment. 
Thread-Index: AQHTJWSHSywMzSz8o0OJud48nG50GQ== 
Date: Mon, 4 Sep 2017 10:00:00 +0000 
Message-ID: 
                <4aade2547798441eab5188a7a2436bc1@contoso.com> 
Accept-Language: en-US 
Content-Language: en-US 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: 
                contoso.com 
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: 
                0ffdb402-ec03-42c8-5d32-08d4f37bb517 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1 
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-RecordReviewCfmType: 0 

MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> The email headers are created by the email servers, these details can
>   include who sent the message, the software that was used to compose
>   it, and the email servers that it passed through on its way to the
>   recipient. Hence you are not able to view the header information for
>   the sent messages.